# How to launch the new app from node-webkit app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, node-webkit

Right now Am working on the application which is built by node-webkit.My requirement quit changed..What i need to do is I should run the app2 which is built by node-webkit from the app1 which is also built by node web-kit...Is that possible..Please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [this](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/1045).Hope this will help you!